# Error SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens... en ejecución de sentencia SQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un script en `PHP` que valida parte con `JavaScript`, lo que no entiendo es porque si no tira ningún error no se ejecuta la consulta.

Incluso intenté seteando las variables que son `intergers` en la `BD` y aún así tampoco. Probé también todas las variables con `echo()` para verificar que las variables estuvieran bien escritas, ya no sé qué más hacer la verdad.

Agradecería cualquier aporte ya que estoy realmente perdido.
**informe.php**:

```php
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

echo '<script></script><style>html{background-color:#1b191b;}form{display: none;}</style>';

$arrDatos=array();

$arrDatos['name']=(!empty($_POST['inputName'])) ? array('data'=>$_POST['inputName']) : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Tienes que insertar el nombre del delincuente.');
$arrDatos['dia']=(!empty($_POST['dia']))  ? array('data'=>$_POST['dia'])  : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Tienes que insertar la fecha del delito.');
$arrDatos['mes']=(!empty($_POST['mes']))  ? array('data'=>$_POST['mes'])  : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Tienes que insertar la fecha del delito.');
$arrDatos['ano']=(!empty($_POST['ano']))  ? array('data'=>$_POST['ano'])  : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Tienes que insertar la fecha del delito.');
$arrDatos['delit']=(!empty($_POST['inputDelit'])) ? array('data'=>$_POST['inputDelit']) : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Tienes que insertar el delito ocurrido.');
$arrDatos['arrest']=(!empty($_POST['arrestado'])) ? array('data'=>$_POST['arrestado']) : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Tiene que indicar si fue o no arrestado.');
if($arrDatos['arrest']['data']=='checked0'){
    $arrDatos['prioridad']=(!empty($_POST['prioridad'])) ? array('data'=>$_POST['prioridad']) : array('id'=> 1, 'msg'=>'Tiene que indicar la prioridad del pedido de captura.');
}

if(array_column($arrDatos, 'msg')) {
    $msgs=implode(" ",array_column($arrDatos, 'msg'));
    exit('<script>alert("'.$msgs.'");location.href="/pcu/faccion/";</script>');
}

else {
    if($arrDatos['arrest']['data']=='checked0'){
        $pjsql="SELECT Nombre, ID FROM sv_cuentas WHERE Nombre = :nam";
        $stmtpj=$db->prepare($pjsql);
        $arrParams=array(":nam"=>$arrDatos['name']['data']);
        $stmtpj->execute($arrParams);
        while($rowcheck = $stmtpj->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $pj_nombrere = $rowcheck['Nombre'];
            $pj_idre = $rowcheck['ID'];
        }
        settype($pj_idre, "integer");settype($arrDatos['dia']['data'], "integer");settype($arrDatos['mes']['data'], "integer");settype($arrDatos['ano']['data'], "integer");
        if($_POST['inputOthers']){$descripcion=$arrDatos['delit']['data'].'Otros implicados: '.$_POST['inputOthers'];}
        if(!$pj_nombrere){
            exit('<script>alert("El usuario del que informaste no existe.");location.href="/pcu/faccion/";</script>');
        }
        else{
            ECHO "<script>alert('Hasta acá llega.');</SCRIPT>";
            $registrosql=("INSERT INTO sv_pdbusquedas (JSQLID, Dia, Mes, Anio, Prioridad, Oficial, Descripcion) VALUES (:id, :dia, :mes, :ano, :prioridad, :oficial, :descripcion)");
            $stmt2=$db->prepare($registrosql);
            $stmt2->execute(array(":id" => $pj_idre, ":dia" => $arrDatos['dia']['data'], ":mes" => $arrDatos['mes']['data'], ":ano" => $arrDatos['ano']['data'], $arrDatos['prioridad']['data'], ":oficial" =>$pj_nickname, ":descripcion" => $descripcion));
            if($stmt2){
                echo '<script>alert("'.$stmt2.'Acá no llega nunca.");location.href="/pcu/faccion/";</script>';
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'a';
    }}
}
?>
```

Comment: Saca esto aparte en una variable y muéstralo: `$arrParams=array(":id" => $pj_idre, ":dia" => $arrDatos['dia']['data'], ":mes" => $arrDatos['mes']['data'], ":ano" => $arrDatos['ano']['data'], $arrDatos['prioridad']['data'], ":oficial" =>$pj_nickname, ":descripcion" => $descripcion);` y luego, `var_dump($arrParams);` Hay que saber lo que estás pasando realmente al `execute`.  Otra cosa, puedes poner un else, para que te imprima el error: `if($stmt2){ echo '<script>alert("'.$stmt2.'Acá no llega nunca.");location.href="/pcu/faccion/";</script>'; }else{print_r($db->errorInfo());`

Comment: En vez del `print_r($db->errorInfo());` puede ser un `alert`... no sé, nunca me han gustado esas mezclas de código Javascript en código PHP, prefiero usar Ajax para esto, recogiendo la información llana y pasándola al cliente, monstrándola entonces allí.

Comment: Bueno, resulta que la variabla `$arrParams`, es decir que la `$arrDatos` igual, tienen algún error, al intentar ponerla me salta el error de que el 'else' era inesperado. Por otro lado el `$db->errorInfo();`, imprime: `Invalid parameter number` en la correspondiente línea al `execute()`, además de que imprime las variables $_POST:

Comment: `array(8) {
  ["inputName"]=>
  string(13) "Ricardo_Darin"
  ["dia"]=>
  string(2) "05"
  ["mes"]=>
  string(2) "04"
  ["ano"]=>
  string(4) "2019"
  ["inputOthers"]=>
  string(67) "Estaba corriendo."
  ["inputDelit"]=>
  string(85) "Cuando vi los hechos procedí a disparar y ambos se dieron a la fuga."
  ["arrestado"]=>
  string(8) "checked0"
  ["prioridad"]=>
  string(4) "Alta"
}`

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario, ni a qué corresponde le `var_dump` que muestras ¿?

Comment: Mis disculpas, a un `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: Ya, pero muestra un `var_dump` de los parámetros que pasas en el `execute`, el mensaje de error es claro, dice que faltan o sobran parámetros: *`invalid parameter number`*, por eso te dije que los saques aparte en un array y hagas un `var_dump`, esas cosas son las primeras que hay que verificar en estos casos.

Comment: Por ejemplo, en la parte de prioridad tienes un error, lo tienes así: `$arrDatos['prioridad']['data'],` y debe estar así: **`":prioridad" => $arrDatos['prioridad']['data']`**

Comment: ¿Puedes poner eso en una respuesta? Así la voto como correcta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje de error *`invalid parameter number`*  indica que el número de parámetros de la consulta preparada y los que pasas en el `execute` no coinciden.

Por claridad de código y para facilitar la depuración, siempre conviene sacar los parámetros en una variable e incluso identar los valores de los arrays. Si lo haces así verás el error de inmediato:

```
$arrParams=array(
                    ":id" => $pj_idre, 
                    ":dia" => $arrDatos['dia']['data'], 
                    ":mes" => $arrDatos['mes']['data'], 
                    ":ano" => $arrDatos['ano']['data'], 
                    $arrDatos['prioridad']['data'], 
                    ":oficial" =>$pj_nickname, 
                    ":descripcion" => $descripcion
                );
```

Ahí se ve con toda claridad que el nombre del parámetro `:prioridad` falta, y podrás corregirlo:

```
$arrParams=array(
                    ":id" => $pj_idre, 
                    ":dia" => $arrDatos['dia']['data'], 
                    ":mes" => $arrDatos['mes']['data'], 
                    ":ano" => $arrDatos['ano']['data'], 
                    ":prioridad" => $arrDatos['prioridad']['data'], 
                    ":oficial" =>$pj_nickname, 
                    ":descripcion" => $descripcion
                );
```

### Recomendación: cada cosa en su contexto

Al ver que tienes trozos de scripts Javascript mezclado en el código PHP, recomendaría que evites esa práctica. Hoy día gracias a Ajax puedes escribir un código mucho más organizado donde en el servidor se procesa cualquier información y emites al cliente una respuesta sea a través de un JSON o de texto directo para mostrarla en un contenedor, en un alert, redirigir, etc.

Este tipo de mezclas hoy día tienen poco sentido:

```
    if(!$pj_nombrere){
        exit('<script>alert("El usuario del que informaste no existe.");location.href="/pcu/faccion/";</script>');
    }
    else{
        //...
    }
```

Eso debería ser enviado como respuesta al cliente, y programar de su lado lo que haya que hacer en cada caso.